# Apache при попытке настроить userdir выдает Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled

Tags: macos, apache-modules, apache2.4

При запуске `apache2` делаю загрузку модуля `userdir` и затем настраиваю его:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root
        UserDir disabled

        <Directory />
            AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                Require all granted
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

и получаю ошибку

```
Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Загрузка модуля заранее производится

```
LoadModule userdir_module ${APACHE2_MODS}/mod_userdir.so
```

Запускаю проект под High Sierra, проект рабочий, у соседей на Ubuntu и apache 2.2 запускается без проблем.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `Require` не относится к модулю userdir. А также (в общем виде) директива не совместима между версиями 2.2 и 2.4. То что написано у вас в конфиге, скорее относится к версии 2.4. И убедитесь, что подключен модуль authz_core.

Comment: @defrag спасибо за комментарий! author_core подключен, а почему у соседей она работает? И как правильно сделать? Если делаю  Order та же ошибка только на order

Comment: Ну это самый частый «аргумент» - а вот у других работает! Если у вас действительно версия 2.4, и действительно подключен модуль mod_authz_core, то ошибки «Invalid command Require” быть не должно.

Comment: @defrag вы правы, модули лежали в странной папке, удалила, переустановила Apache - brew install apache2 модулей нигде не появилось. Похоже какие то пакеты еще надо ставить

Comment: Я не силен в макоси, поэтому не подскажу как там что правильно ставить.